# Are bilinear functionals continuous, in general?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, continuity

If we define the implicit topology on an arbitrary real vector space $V$ to be the minimal topology in which all linear functionals $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are continuous, then are bilinear functions $V\times W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ necessarily continuous?

I figured out that this way of giving a real vector space a topology is a nice way to introduce the standard topology of finitely-dimensional real vector spaces, without using the notion of a base. Because it is the standard topology, all well-known properties are true. But is it true in infinitely-dimensional case? Are bilinear functions continuous? Among things that I figured out are:

1. A function to $V$ is continuous iff it is continuous when composed with all linear functionals $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
2. (I hoped this might help identify continuous functions **from** $V$) For arbitrary base $B$ identify the space $V$ with the space of functions $B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with only finitely many non-zero points. Now restrict the product topology of all functions $B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ to $V$. Call this topology the topology generated by base $B$. Now, my topology is the smallest topology which contains topologies generated by each base,
3. If one of $V$ or $W$ is finitely-dimensional, then bilinear functions $V\times W\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are indeed continuous.
4. Every subspace of $V$ is a closed set, and the topology restricted to it is the same as the one that is implicitly defined on it.
5. The topological product of implicit topologies is the implicit topology of the cartesian product of vector spaces (i.e. my implicit topology and vector space cartesian product commute).

What I tried to do next is to consider an example where both $V$ and $W$ are the space of polynomials (with real coefficients) and where the bilinear functional is $(p,q)\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^\infty p_i q_i$ ($p_i$ is the $i$-th coefficient of the polynomial $p$, and the same holds for $q_i$). I really couldn't derive anything meaningful about this example...